# Can't use old window in Selenium with firefox and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
# filename: LudusLogin
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import title_is
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time


def login():
    # Firefox driver for running window
    driver = Firefox()

    # Going to website
    driver.get("website")

    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(title_is("Meddelelser"))

    # Login with credentials from .env
    load_dotenv()

    usr = os.getenv("usr")
    passwd = os.getenv("passwd")

    usr_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#brugerIdField")
    passwd_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#kodeordField")

    usr_field.send_keys(usr)
    passwd_field.send_keys(passwd)
    passwd_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Closing messages
    time.sleep(2)
    close_btn_meddelelser = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "v-window-closebox")
    close_btn_meddelelser.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(title_is("Aktuelt"))

    # window_handle = driver.window_handles
    window_handle = driver.window_handles[0]

    return window_handle
```

**Next File**
I want to switch to the window from code above and continue executing code in the same window

```py
# filename: Main.py
import LudusLogin
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import title_is
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

handle = LudusLogin.login()
print(handle)
driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
driver.switch_to.window(handle)

skema_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.v-menubar-menuitem:nth-child(4)")
skema_btn.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(title_is("Skemaer"))
```

I want to be able to have all scripts for the website in Main.py or other files and just the login in one file. When I try as shown i get the **error**: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to locate window:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new instance of Firefox driver in `Main.py` first:

```
driver = Firefox()
```

Alter `login` method and in `LudusLogin.py` and make a change to accept input variable named `driver`. Then delete line

```
driver = Firefox()
```

inside `LudusLogin.py` and let `login` body to use input variable `driver`.

Now in `Main.py` you have `driver` variable to use after calling `login` method. the `driver` which you instantiate only once.